# For some reason this specific line of text gets spaced out once

Tags: c#

[What appears in my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDApd.png)

Here's the code I've used:

```cs
Random numberGen = new Random(); 

int roll01 = 0;
int roll02 = 1;
int attempts = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Press spacebar to roll the dice.");
         
while(roll01 != roll02) 
{
    Console.ReadKey();
            
    roll01 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);  
    roll02 = numberGen.Next(1, 7);
            
    Console.WriteLine("Roll 1: " + roll01);
    Console.WriteLine("Roll 2: " + roll02 + "\n");                
    attempts++;
}
```

I really dont know why `Console.WriteLine("Roll 1: " + roll01);` doesn't work, yet `Console.WriteLine("Roll 2: " + roll02 + "\n");` does... I'd appreciate any help I could get (I'm a beginner so dont expect me to understand anything too fancy.) Thanks.

Comment: You are literally telling the user to press the spacebar, so why are you confused that there's a space?

Comment: Change `Console.WriteLine("Press spacebar to roll the dice.");` this to this: `Console.Write("Press spacebar to roll the dice.");` - Edit: You also need to change this: `Console.WriteLine("Roll 1: " + roll01);` to this: `Console.WriteLine("\nRoll 1: " + roll01);`

Comment: If you want an extra line in your output, I would suggest that it's "more correct" to call `Console.WriteLine` again with no arguments, rather than adding a literal line feed to the `string` you're writing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am such an idiot... thanks

Comment: We all tend to see what we expect to see at times. We just have to try to keep it to a minimum. 